# Setting up VHD Boot for Windows 8.1 32-bit OS on 64-bit UEFI

Tags: vhd, windows-8.1, uefi

I have a Surface Pro 3 that natively runs Windows 8.1 64-bit. By extension, the UEFI on the device has a 64-bit boot loader.

I am attempting to setup the device to allow a VHD boot into a Windows 8.1 32-bit OS. When I finally boot into the VHD image, I end up with an error message stating the image is corrupt.

The steps I took were as follows. First I created the vhdx file:

```
diskpart
create vdisk file=D:\windows8.vhdx maximum=40960 type=expandable
select vdisk file=D:\windows8.vhdx
attach vdisk
create partition primary
assign letter=F
format quick label=VHDX
exit
```

Then I mounted the Windows 8.1 32-bit image to my `E:\` drive and applied the image to the .vhdx file:

```
dism /Apply-Imaeg /ImageFile:E:\Sources\install.wim /index:1 /ApplyDir:F:\
```

After doing so, I used bcdboot to generate the boot loader entries:

```
F:\Windows\system32\bcdboot.exe F:\Windows /s F: /f ALL /d /addlast
```

Afterwards, I looked up the boot loader entry and added the hypervisor launch type and an appropriate description:

```
bcdedit /v
bcdedit /set {GUID-FROM-ABOVE} hypervisorlaunchtype auto
bcdedit /set {GUID-FROM-ABOVE} description Windows 8.1 32-bit (VHDX)
```

Then I rebooted the device so that I could select the VHD boot image:

```
shutdown /r /o /t 0
```

When I finally booted into the image I got the following error:

```
Your PC needs to be repaired
File: \windows\system32\winload.efi
Error code: 0xc0000359  
The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I used this script to create VHDs: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Convert-WindowsImageps1-0fe23a8f This allows you to create GPT VHDX files.

Comment: @magicandre1981: I tried using this as well but I still get an error code. In this case, it returns `0x0000225`.

Comment: try the full path, not the relative: **bcdedit /set {guid} path C:\Windows\system32\winload.efi**

Comment: @magicandre1981: This is a *VHD* boot. The path is supposed to be a relative path as the bootloader mounts the VHD before searching for the winload.

Comment: @MikeBailey - Added some more info, I'm wondering if you ever found a way around?

Answer (score 2):

Additional updated information about [UEFI Windows Cross-Platform Booting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/deploy/windows-deployment-scenarios-and-tools).

> **Windows support for UEFI**
>
> Microsoft started with support for EFI 1.10 on servers and then added
>   support for UEFI on both clients and servers.
>
> With UEFI 2.3.1, there are both x86 and x64 versions of UEFI. Windows
>   10 supports both. However, UEFI does not support cross-platform boot.
>   This means that a computer that has UEFI x64 can run only a 64-bit
>   operating system, and a computer that has UEFI x86 can run only a
>   32-bit operating system.

---

Addition of some info on Boot from Windows 10, Windows To Go for UEFI vs Legacy | 32 vs 64 bit.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt185782(v=vs.85).aspx

> Checking for architectural compatibility between the host PC and the
>   Windows To Go drive
>
> In addition to the USB boot support in the BIOS, the Windows 10 image
>   on your Windows To Go drive must be compatible with the processor
>   architecture and the firmware of the host PC as shown in the table
>   below.

---

I also have a Surface Pro 3 and have found and experienced some peculiarities.

Surface Pro 3 has the following features/ issues:

- It's a **UEFI "only" device**
- **No Legacy BIOS / CSM (Compatibility Mode) Support** (Most machines will have a setting in the firmware that allows you to enable that, but not in this machine)
- Hence, **booting older operating systems** on such new machines is not supported.
- It doesn't seem to be supported and most likely can't be done; unless someone finds a hack or workaround (not officially supported by Microsoft).

  - Also, Surface Pro 3 is factory shipped with Secure Boot, TPM and its hard drive & partitions are by default in Bit lockered state.
  - These 3 things cause a whole different sent of issues with booting OSes.
  - To Native Boot of VHDs I had to disable them

Why is this an issue and why is this happening?

An example on a similar note:

- I had a lot of trouble trying to boot Windows 7 x64 SP1 on a Toshiba laptop last year despite it having legacy CSM mode
- It had some **Firmware / GOP  driver** issues as pointed out here on MSFN. 
  http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/172462-migrating-windows-7-or-8-install-from-bios-machine-to-native-boot-vhd/
- I don't understand completely what the GOP issue was and cant explain it further

**Essential Summary:** 
**In newer machines (like Surface Pro 3 and that Toshiba laptop) OEMs have started ripping out certain things (examples listed above) that would used to help with backward compatibility to boot and run older Operating Systems.**

Quoting with a similar [thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfpro-surfusingpro/need-to-change-os-to-windows-8-32bit/b0fa9bc9-2134-43c5-80bc-32e2c8b399d8?auth=1) and [reply](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfpro-surfusingpro/need-to-change-os-to-windows-8-32bit/b0fa9bc9-2134-43c5-80bc-32e2c8b399d8?page=2) by "JHoff80" on Microsoft Forums:

> Sorry, but I think you're SOL.  My understanding of it is that UEFI
>   has to have the same architecture as the OS you're trying to run.  The
>   Surface Pro UEFI is 64-bit, and so you can only run a 64-bit OS on
>   there.
>
> Unfortunately, the Surface also does not have the "Legacy
>   Boot" option to emulate a BIOS like many other PCs have.

### Additional articles & information about 32-bit UEFI booting:

It appears there are issues & limitations around 32 bit UEFI booting, especially with variety of Hardware + Firmware + Partition + OS combinations.

I came across the following and it might have some relevance here to help people debug & resolve their problems.

**Ubuntu site quoted below.** 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

> **To install Ubuntu in UEFI mode:**
>
> 1. Use a 64bit disk of Ubuntu. ([Ubuntu32bit cannot be easily installed in UEFI mode](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1025555). This is a problem if 32-bit UEFI is the
>      only way your computer can boot, e.g. if you have a modern Intel Atom
>      based laptop. In this case, you will need [a complicated
>      work-around](https://github.com/lopaka/instructions/blob/master/ubuntu-14.10-install-asus-x205ta.md).)

**32-bit UEFI booting using E2B:**
http://rmprepusb.blogspot.com/2014/09/32-bit-uefi-booting-using-e2b.html

- **Easy2Boot & RMprepUSB by [Steve](https://superuser.com/users/220374/stevesi) are tools to multi-boot huge variety of systems:**
  http://www.easy2boot.com | http://rmprepusb.com

> Some Intel Atom-based Tablets are 32-bit UEFI only (even if the Atom CPU itself is a 64-bit CPU).

> The problem is that if the user's Tablet is a 32-bit UEFI system (that does not support CSM\MBR mode) then they need to find an OS that is 32-bit UEFI bootable - and there are not many of these around!

> Note: If they are 32-bit UEFI bootable, then they will contain the \EFI\boot\bootia32.efi file (amongst others). If they don't contain that file then they won't boot from an E2B USB drive on a 32-bit UEFI system.

> Instructions (found by Karan) for booting Ubuntu from the Asus T100 are [here][5]. Karan found that he could copy the bootia32.efi file from [here][6] to a Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit .imgPTN file (\EFI\boot\bootia32.efi) and his Intel Atom system booted. I suspect this will only work if your firmware is 32-bit UEFI but your CPU is 64-bit though, like Karan's [Notion Ink CN89553G][7].

Similar: https://superuser.com/a/889802/183467

> Some systems do not support Legacy\CSM\MBR booting. Look in the firmware settings for these options and also disable Fast Boot. Systems with no Legacy\CSM\MBR option can only UEFI-boot. LinuxLive and E2B are for Legacy\CSM\MBR booting systems.

Comment: @Mokubai - Please explain to me and elaborate what kind of solution you would like? I tried it out as well and Surface Pro 3 has not allowed me (& others that I can find on the web) to boot a 32 bit Operating System - So far. Given my and others experience, its not possible. Is that not good enough? 

It is not a question anymore. It is answer addressing the OPs question, that this is not possible and an added insight into why newer UEFI firmware's like that of SPro3 give trouble in booting older OSes. 

If you or someone has found a way, please do share. But, this is an answer for now.

Comment: I upvote for your research but I believe what "JHoff80" said is wrong. Obviously one can run a 32bit UEFI OS in a 64bit UEFI machine(say, install in a physical partition), the problem is, a 32bit OS has to be loaded from a 32bit UEFI loader, and when you use bcdedit in your current OS, you're working with the 64bit loader thus wouldn't work.

Comment: Chris C - From my research and efforts on 2 machines I have faced lot of issues around UEFI and GPT booting. For now, this is an answer. 

On further research, if you (or myself in the future) can find a way to get past this answer and limitation, then that would be an answer / solution that will supersede this. So, until proven practically, the theoretical maybe that can be done is so far not valid for the Surface Pro 3.

Comment: I have been running multiple 64 bit OS VHD native boots working on Surface Pro 3 and I cannot comment on OPs question to ask him, whether he tried any with 64 bit before going for 32 bit?

Comment: @Chris.C - What you are saying is a different scenario, which is not the OPs question. This is very specifically Native Boot of VHDs which is pretty much all I have been doing for a while. Again, we failed and we cant do it and we found that Microsoft support forums say that its not possible. 
If you can do it on a Surface Pro 3 (which is a very unique beast of its own.. so rules that apply to other machines may not apply to it) then please post the answer/ solution that works.

Comment: And for all the effort research around booting VHDs on SP3, I am still negative on rep and unable to comment on OPs question. http://superuser.com/users/183467/alex-s?tab=reputation PS: I dont care about rep points but for the right intent, actually see whatever can be added to help.

Comment: @Chris.C - I think this could possibly becoming a Wiki for 32 bit UEFI booting issues with new HW + FW + OS combinations (see updated info). 
- Would you please share the 'example' of positive experience(s) you had? (mentioned in your previous comment) With specifics of which HW+FW+OS etc?